# Get total of the column with where condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the total of the column `Price` with condition `BillPaid` column value should be `0`.

My code block is

```
public function countDue()
{
    $getTotalDue = DB::table('ordered_books')                                
                            ->where('BillPaid', 0)
                            ->sum('Price')
                            ->get(); 
    return response()->json($getTotalDue);
    return compact('getTotalDue');
}
```

controller code block for calling the `countDue` method.

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.booksin', $this->countDue());
    }
```

view page

```
<table id="showBooksIn" class="table table-bordered gridview">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Total Due Amount</th></tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        @if(isset($getTotalDue))
            @foreach($getTotalDue as $data)
                <tr>
                    <td> {{$data}} </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
  </tbody>          
</table>
```

but I am getting error as :

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function get() on float
```

My table structure is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#aggregates), you don't need to chain the `get()` method there.

```
public function countDue(){
    $getTotalDue = DB::table('ordered_books')->where('BillPaid', 0)->sum('Price');    //Get the sum using the Laravel's query builder aggregate sum method

    return $getTotalDue;
}

public function create()
{
    return view('pages.booksin', ['getTotalDue' => $this->countDue()]);   //Pass the `countDue()` method output to the view
}
```

**Note**

This is a single value, you might want to display it inside a header or paragraph element like so:

```
@if(isset($getTotalDue))
    <h2>{{ $getTotalDue }}</h2>
@endif
```

Comment: getting error as `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`

Comment: I've posted the code block where I am calling the method. Please check my added code blocks

Comment: Oh... I have edited my answer based on the extra information you provided.

Comment: Thank You, but still getting error as `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `. How to edit the table code block, I think I am getting error because the output is only a single value. But I am not sure.

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't see your view on time. The sum is a single value hence you cannot loop through it. Just output it using a `paragraph` or `td` tag.

Comment: One last question, though it should be new post but I am asking just for help. Can I show the data `getTotalDue` in comma separated format. eg. 44,990. Thank You!

Comment: @JinalSomaiya please can you show me the code. How can I do that?

Comment: `{{ number_format($getTotalDue) }}`.... http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the get() method in there.

```
    public function countDue()
{
    $getTotalDue = DB::table('ordered_books')                                
                            ->where('BillPaid', 0)
                            ->sum('Price'); 
    return response()->json($getTotalDue);
    return compact('getTotalDue');
}
```

Also, you have two return statements right after another, making the second one unreachable.

The second argument of the view() method needs to be an array, or you could use the with() syntax. You should try the following code, and passing the $getTotalDue into the view.

```
public function create()
    {
         $getTotalDue = DB::table('ordered_books')                                
                            ->where('BillPaid', 0)
                            ->sum('Price');
        return view('pages.booksin')->with(['getTotalDue' => $getTotalDue]);
    }
```

Comment: Getting error as `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`

Comment: where you used array_merge

Comment: @Polaris I think the error is due to the variable `getTotalDue`. Is the output of the query is an `Array`?

Comment: @nischalinn No, it should just return the sum. Perhaps try return response()->json(json_encode($getTotalDue));

Comment: `response->json();` does `json_encode()` behind the scene.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya Hmm... Post your entire error output log please

Comment: @Polaris I've added the code blocks where I am calling `countDue()` method and also the table block. Please check. Thank You!!!

Comment: @nischalinn I edited my answer, check my post for the code.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use get()

```
$getTotalDue = DB::table('ordered_books')                                
                            ->where('BillPaid', 0)
                            ->sum('Price');
```

will return a float with your sum value